# Javascript maximum size for types?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ecma262

Looking into javascript types I'm trying to find out what the maximum storage size for some data types are. For instance, I set up a quick recursive algo to increase var size till the browser crashes, which ends up being somewhere close to 128mb (or maybe it's 256) for strings on my existing version of chrome.

I've been doing it the painful way because I couldn't find any specs on this, but constant browser crashes make this a painful trial (try catch seems useless for some reason with this particular issue).

I'm looking for information about maximum storage size for the other types also (array, object, functions, strings, numbers, bools...)

EMCA-262 section 8.4 is vague on this

> The length of a String is the number of elements (i.e., 16-bit values) within it. The empty String has length zero and therefore contains no elements.

...so perhaps this is something that needs to be identified as implemented in browsers?

ECMA does however tell us about numbers, for example,

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 2^64−2^53+3) values, representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, except that the 9007199254740990 (that is, 2^53−2) distinct “Not-a-Number” values of the IEEE Standard are represented in ECMAScript as a single special NaN value.

But then I don't see anything about objects.

What can I expect for use in browsers? Is there any code-base out there that helps manage very large objects and strings?

How much memory can I allocate in a single script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already stated, the specification does **not** state any size limits / requirements for types besides `Number`.

So this is definitally left to the implementation.

For example, Chrome's limit on strings seems to be hard coded at around 512mb (and less on 32bit).

> This puts a limit on the maximally 
>   possible allocation request in 32-bit versions of 2^27-1. The maximal flat string 
>   length is ~2^28 (512MB space), and the maximal string length is 2^29-1, so neither of 
>   these limits catch the problem (we would throw an Out-Of-Memory exception instead if 
>   they did).

See: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=362#c9

As far as the other browsers go, this would need some research e.g. looking into Firefox's code. But I doubt we can do the same for IE / Opera.

Comment: So there is really no central area for this type of information?

Comment: Not really, but then again if you're hitting those limits you're most likely doing something that doesn't fit the browser environment :) Although it's still interesting to get to the information, but as I said you will have to do a lot of digging on google etc. to find it.

Comment: Like in any other language, asking `what is the maximum length of a string` is analogous to asking `how mush RAM does the computer have`. Implementations may or may not limit it (such as the case of Chrome) but at the end of the day a string is merely an array of bytes (and in fact in most javascript interpreters out there it is just a thin wrapper around null-terminated C strings).

Comment: @siebetman That is very true, but we're limited in practice by the implementation, or cpu architecture... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/ Is there a set memory size for the program? Lots of questions that are important if we're going into this "everything in the cloud" idea.

Comment: @slebetman The OP has asked, "what is the maximum length of a string in Javascript that I can I safely expect to use in browsers?". That is a valid question and not at all analogous to asking "how much RAM does the computer have". Physical memory is just _one_ of the limiting factors. Other, much tighter constraints limit the string length. Now, in 2015, Chrome still blows up when a string is 2^28 characters long.

Comment: @hashchange: I believe I DID mention the Chrome thing in my comment. The OP didn't ask browser specific limitations but limitation imposed by the language - and the answer is there is none

Answer (score 5):

ECMA section 6.1.4 is explicit about this.

"The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of 2^53-1 elements"

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this currently, I can not send the results back via json as it is html based.  And the data is truncated to a specific size, and the excess data is dropped.  I am not positive yet on the number of characters in the returned results, but it is far less then 2^27...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31646433)

Answer (score -1):

I have listed some typical limits for strings in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28841863/508355). Basically, you are in safe territory up to a string length of 2<sup>27</sup> characters.