# how to declare long size variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

I am trying to assign base 64 string of big pdf  in javascript variable but
its not assign complete string properly.so what I do for assign complete string in javascript variable in nodejs.My code is:

```
 var child = exec('java -jar .....some variables,
                    function (error,stdout,stderr) {
  // stdout recieved base 64 pdf string
  // pdf size is aprox 15 mb so string also large
        console.log('Output value -> ' + stdout);
                            var data = {
                                base64PdfString: stdout
                            } 
    })
```

so when I try execute this function Its return large base64 string in my callback variable but when want to use this variable than string is not recieved completely so pdf is not create properly.its create some error in pdf.thanks.

Comment: I have the impression that `console.log` truncates it, but it's actually there. Have you tried writing it to a file?

Comment: 15MB should not be a problem. Users have tested with even strings of size  1GB. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24154168/1281089