# javascript: string limited to 268,400,000 length?

Tags: javascript, string, size, limit

With javascript and chrome (on electron) I am reading files in chunks and attaching it to a string. I can see now that if I try to read a file of 462Mb, I get the error `RangeError: Invalid string length` and if in every chunk I print the string length, the lass reading shows `268,400,000`, reading chunks of `100,000`.

What is this error about? A javascript string limit? My computer saying stop? I can see that CPU keeps below 50% and memory doesn't go higher than 55%.

I am about to think about a workaround, but I cannot find anything about a length limit, so maybe I am facing another type of error?

The code I'm using to read files

```
    var start, temp_end, end;
    var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 100000;

    function readFile(file_to_read,param) {
        if (param.start < param.end) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                var chunk = file_to_read.file.slice(param.start, param.temp_end);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    if (e.target.readyState == 2) { // the file is being uploaded in chunks, and the chunk has been successfully read
                        document.getElementById('file_monitor').max = param.end;
                        document.getElementById('file_monitor').value = param.temp_end;
                        //file.data += new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(e.target.result);
                        Promise.resolve()
                        .then(function(){
                            file_to_read.data += e.target.result;
                        }).then(function(){
                            param.start = param.temp_end; // 0 if a new file, the previous one if still reading the same file
                            param.temp_end = param.start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                            if (param.temp_end > param.end)
                                param.temp_end = param.end;
                            resolve(readFile(file_to_read,param));
                        }).catch(function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                            console.log(file_to_read.data.length);
                            console.log(file_to_read.data);
                            console.log(e.target.result);
                            resolve();
                        });
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsText(chunk);
        //      reader.readAsBinaryString(chunk);
            });
        } else
            return Promise.resolve();
    }
```

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695187/javascript-maximum-size-for-types) help?

Comment: Yes, definitively :)