# The limitation of responseText in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

As we are known, for XMLHttpRequest, method **'GET'** has a limitation of *URL* length in characters, and **'POST'** does not.

So my question is if there is a limitation of `responseText` or `responseXML` ?_? i.e. the data which JS get from the Ajax, not the data we post or length of URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Javascript maximum size for types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695187/javascript-maximum-size-for-types)

Unless the browser specified otherwise, variable sizes are not subject to a restriction. As for Ajax: There's no limit, unless defined server-side